# Schema (XSD) for Microsoft .NET configuration file

Tags: .net, configuration-files, msdn

I'm searching the XSD (XML Schema) for the Microsoft .NET application configuration files. Till now I found only this: [Configuration File Schema for the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1fk1t1t0.aspx) but I'm more interested in the XSD.

Or - asked in general - I search also XSDs in general for .NET configuration files [listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xtk877y.aspx).

I've Visual Studio 2008 and don't see such files as in the first answer...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[DotNetConfig.xsd](https://gist.github.com/eed3si9n/5dd7dd98ad2b3f668928b23477de35a3) updated by [Peter Ritchie](https://web.archive.org/web/20090421154432/http://peterritchie.com/Hamlet/Downloads/74.aspx) based on `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 8\Xml\Schemas\DotNetConfig.xsd`. See [Schema Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255821.aspx).

Comment: It's somehow frustrating that those schemas aren't online... I just searched http://schemas.microsoft.com but there isn't something